# conditional compilation at statement level

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I am creating a wrapper for a stream that has optional values

I defined the temp object as follows (`SourcePoint` is a template parameter)

```
struct T
{

    POINT10 point;// always there
    typename enable_if<needsTime<SourcePoint>::val, GPSTime10>::type time;
    typename enable_if<needsRGB<SourcePoint>::val, RGB12>::type rgb;

} it;
```

now in my write function I need to skip the time object if `needsTime<SourcePoint>` is false

```
void write (const SourcePoint& rec)
{
  struct T it;
  it.point.X_ = rec.X * 100;
  it.point.Y_ = rec.Y * 100;
  it.point.Z_ = rec.Z * 100;
  //TODO convert to integral properly => find scale

  //FIXME conditional compilation

  if (needsTime<SourcePoint>)
    it.time.gpsTime = rec.T;//<-- right here

  //...

}
```

however because `it.time.gpsTime = rec.T;` is not semantically valid if needsTime is false this won't work

I want to avoid using overloaded tagged functions for this

is there any static_if hack available that I can use here

Comment: "I don't want to use a solution. No reason. Is there any hack that solves this?" WTF

Comment: `enable_if` doesn't work the way you're using it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes because I don't want to bloat that header any more, if there is no other option I'll go that route

Comment: @catscradle I can replace that with a `boost::conditional<needsRGB<SourcePoint>::val, RGB12, void[]>::type` for the desired effect